# How to sort UITableView sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have an array of objects with date inside.
Now I need to group my objects in UITableView by this date.
For examle:

```
0-{10-14; Obj1};
1-{10-14; Obj2};
2-{10-15; Obj3};
3-{10-15; Obj4};
```

I need to view it on my UITableView like this

```
10-14
    0-{10-14; Obj1};
    1-{10-14; Obj2};
10-15
    2-{10-15; Obj3};
    3-{10-15; Obj4};
```

To resolve I've done next; I've splited my array into NSDictationary with this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *preResult = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (ClientMessage *message in array) {
    NSMutableArray *mArray = [preResult objectForKey:message.formattedDate];
    if (mArray == nil) {
        mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [preResult setObject: mArray forKey:message.formattedDate];
    }
    [mArray addObject:message];
}
```

And my Table view shows me what i want, but it shows in wrong order; (my array was sorted by date)
I know tha i can't sort NSDictationary, in that case how can i sort my values in table view? Or Is there another way to group my values without NSDictationary?

Comment: You can't sort an NSDictionary.  Use an array of arrays.

Comment: Change *preResult* to an array, and sort it at the end of the code you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've finished loading the dictionary with all the values, you'll want to sort each array within the dictionary...

```
for (NSString *key in [preResult allKeys])
{
    NSMutableArray *mArray = [preResult objectForKey:key];
      // sort array to achieve the desired result
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"formattedDate" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [mArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
      // reset newly sorted array for key inside the dictionary
    [preResult sortedArray forKey:key];
}
```